# Issue when enumerating windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm having a problem when trying to run the following code:

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    id = GetCurrentProcessId();
    EnumWindows(hEnumWindows, NULL);

    Sleep(5000);
    //MoveWindow(hThis, 450, 450, 100, 100, TRUE);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//header.h

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD id = 0;
HWND hThis = NULL;

BOOL CALLBACK hEnumWindows(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);

    if (pid == id)
    {
        hThis = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER);
        if (!hThis)
        {
            cout << "Error getting window!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            char *buffer = nullptr;
            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hThis);
            buffer = (char*)malloc(size+1);
            if (buffer != nullptr)
            {
                GetWindowText(hThis, buffer, size);
                cout << pid << ":" << buffer << endl;
                free(buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

When I run this code nothing is output to the screen almost as if the program is not attached. I tried running it under a console and windows subsystem in `VS2013`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see a C-style cast so let's hope not C++ ;)

Comment: @Cyber: I see things like `cout << pid << ` which lead me to believe it's C++.

Comment: This is being compiled on VS2013 with the C++ compiler, I prefer malloc to new and thats why that has been used.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`GetCurrentProcessId` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx), the API

> Retrieves the process identifier of the calling process.

[`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx), on the other hand,

> Retrieves the identifier of the thread that created the specified window and, optionally, the identifier of the process that created the window.
>
> The return value is the identifier of the thread that created the window.

So looking at your call:

```
pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);
```

You're actually getting back a thread ID, not a process ID. So when you compare `pid` to `id`, you're comparing a process ID and a thread ID, and that's just not going to work. Try this instead:

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
```

(Note: I can't actually test whether this works, since `EnumWindows` requires a top-level window to enumerate and I ran this as a console app. Let me know if this answer doesn't work for you and I'll delete it.)

(As a second note, you don't need to use `NULL` anymore, even for WinAPI stuff like `HWND`. `nullptr` will work perfectly fine.)

Comment: You can call `EnumWindows()` in a console app.  Console apps can call Win2 API functions, and `EnumWindows()` enumerates all top-level windows regardless of the type of app that is calling it. You do not need your own top-level window in order to call `EnumWindows()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, but look at what else op's code is doing - it's checking to see if the pid of a top-level window matches this program's pid. Since I just used a quick-and-dirty console app for testing, I didn't have a top-level window available in my app so I couldn't properly perform the pid check.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to find the "Main" window from the ProcessID.. In that case, this MAY help:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

struct WindowHandleStructure
{
    unsigned long PID;
    HWND WindowHandle;
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND WindowHandle, LPARAM lParam)
{
    unsigned long PID = 0;
    WindowHandleStructure* data = reinterpret_cast<WindowHandleStructure*>(lParam);

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, &PID);
    if (data->PID != PID || (GetWindow(WindowHandle, GW_OWNER) && !IsWindowVisible(WindowHandle)))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    data->WindowHandle = WindowHandle;
    return FALSE;
}

HWND FindMainWindow(unsigned long PID)
{
    WindowHandleStructure data = { PID, nullptr };
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&data));
    return data.WindowHandle;
}

int main()
{
    HWND Window = FindMainWindow(GetCurrentProcessId());

    std::wstring Buffer(GetWindowTextLength(Window) + 1, L'\0');
    GetWindowText(Window, &Buffer[0], Buffer.size());

    std::wcout << Buffer.c_str() << L"\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```